# Laravel groupBy when date does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm running the code:

```
DowntimeHistoryMonitoring::whereDate('created_at', '<=', now())->get(['id', 'created_at'])->groupBy(function ($item){
   return $item->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
});
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "2022-11-30": [
    {
      "id": "507a3832-c9d3-4baf-b6a8-ff8100c59897",
      "created_at": "2022-11-30T13:06:42.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "507a3832-c9d3-4baf-b6a8-ff8100c59897",
      "created_at": "2022-11-30T14:06:42.000000Z"
    }
  ],
  "2022-11-29": [
    {
      "id": "507a3832-c9d3-4baf-b6a8-ff8100c59897",
      "created_at": "2022-11-29T13:06:42.000000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do so that I get an empty result if I don't find records, and defined by a limit within the groupBy. Example with a limit of 5:

```
{
  "2022-11-30": [
    {
      "id": "507a3832-c9d3-4baf-b6a8-ff8100c59897",
      "created_at": "2022-11-30T13:06:42.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "507a3832-c9d3-4baf-b6a8-ff8100c59897",
      "created_at": "2022-11-30T14:06:42.000000Z"
    }
  ],
  "2022-11-29": [
    {
      "id": "507a3832-c9d3-4baf-b6a8-ff8100c59897",
      "created_at": "2022-11-29T13:06:42.000000Z"
    }
  ],
  "2022-11-28": [
  ],
  "2022-11-27": [
  ],
  "2022-11-26": [
  ],
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: You can't do that i think, not with groupBy at least, you need to have results to group from, so if there is no record at that date, there is no date to put in the key in the first place. But is it really important ?  you have no record at that date anyway ?

Comment: How would this behave if there are no records? Also how would it behave if there are record for say 10 days ago and 15 days ago only?